# Props undefined after multiple redirects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-props

I am attempting to refactor my React tests for code reuse such that I can return a React component via a function that accepts arguments of a component, Provider store and props to be generated.

It seems that the first function passes the email address correctly, however it doesn't work the same when creating the component itself.

**Test.js**

```
it('perform test', () => {
    const email = '123@test.com

    // define my store
    ...

    provider = getComponent(MyReactComponent, store, {email});
    ...
}
```

**utils.js**

```
export const getComponent = (Component, store = null, ...props) => {
    console.log({props}); // returns { props: [ { email: '123@test.net' } ] }

    const mockStore = configureStore();
    return <Provider store={mockStore(store)}><Component {...props}/></Provider>;
}
```

**MyComponent.jsx**

```
const MyComponent = ({email}) => {
    console.log({email}); // returns undefined
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
export const getComponent = (Component, store = null, ...props) => {
```

To

```
export const getComponent = (Component, store = null, props) => {
```

Props are not meant to be spread as an array.
The way it works with your present code is that you are probably getting object `{email: '123@test.net'}` under prop `0` (due to it being under 0th index in array)

Comment: Awesome! Yes, after I posted this I actually went through and console.logged out what was happening and saw what you stated above for myself.